# how to embedd text input from steganography image?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, steganography

I'm a begineer in Matlab. How to input text by type manual in editbox and embedd it on a bmp image (Steganography) by Matlab programming? I found code using PVD Steganography method.

here is the sample code but it take text from a file, not from what i type manually. please need your advice

```
    % --- Executes on button press in btn_embedd.
    function btn_embedd_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    pilihinput=handles.pilihinput %berhubungan dg pilihan pada radiobutton
    switch handles.pilihinput
        case 1 % IF RADIO BUTTON INPUT TEXT MANUAL CHOOSEN
            password1='';
            password = get(handles.edt_passwordcover, 'string');
            pwd=strcmp(password,'input password');
            pwd1=strcmp(password,password1);
            if (pwd)||(pwd1)
                msgbox('Please input password','ERROR','error');
            else

            imfile=get(handles.txt_lokasicitracover,'String');
            txfile=get(handles.edit_ketikpesan,'String');
            w='';
            k=strcmp(imfile,'input image');
            k1=strcmp(imfile,w);
            k2=strcmp(txfile,'input message');
            k3=strcmp(txfile,w);
            if (k)||(k1)
                msgbox('Please input image','ERROR','error');    
            elseif (k2)||(k3)
                msgbox('Please input message','ERROR','error');
            else

            try
                file=imread(imfile);
                isfile=1;
            catch
                isfile=0;
            end;

            try
                istxfile=fopen(txfile,'rt');
            catch
                istxfile=-1; %If fopen cannot open the file, it returns -1.
            end;

            if(isfile==0)
                    msgbox('image not found. please browse image','ERROR','error');
            elseif(istxfile<0)
                    msgbox('message file is empty. please type message','ERROR','error');
            else
                    h=waitbar(0,'Embedding...');
            for p=1:400, % computation here %
                    waitbar(p/100);
            end;

            [psnr,capa,opfile,full,file]=proses_embedd(imfile,txfile);
            close(h);
            set(handles.txt_nilaipnsr,'String',num2str(psnr));
            set(handles.txt_ukuranpesan,'String',num2str(capa));
            set(handles.txt_kapasitaspesan,'String',num2str(file));
            figure,imshow(imfile);
            figure,imshow(opfile);

            if (full==0)
                msg=strcat(int2str(capa),'bits only embedded please select a large image');
                msgbox(msg,'warning','warn');
            end;

            if (full==1)
                msgbox('SUCCESS!!!','SUCCESS');
            end;
            end;
            end;
            end;

        case 2 % IF RADIO BUTTON TEXT FROM FILE CHOOSEN
            password1='';
            password = get(handles.edt_passwordcover, 'string');
            pwd=strcmp(password,'input password');
            pwd1=strcmp(password,password1);
            if (pwd)||(pwd1)
                msgbox('Please input password','ERROR','error');
            else

            imfile=get(handles.txt_lokasicitracover,'String');
            txfile=get(handles.txt_filepesan,'String');
            w='';
            k=strcmp(imfile,'input image');
            k1=strcmp(imfile,w);
            k2=strcmp(txfile,'input message');
            k3=strcmp(txfile,w);
            if (k)||(k1)
                msgbox('Please input image','ERROR','error');    
            elseif (k2)||(k3)
                msgbox('Please input message','ERROR','error');
            else

            try
                file=imread(imfile);
                isfile=1;
            catch
                isfile=0;
            end;

            try
                istxfile=fopen(txfile,'rt');
            catch
                istxfile=-1;
            end;

            if(isfile==0)
                    msgbox('image not found. please browse image','ERROR','error');
            elseif(istxfile<0)
                    msgbox('message file not found. please browse file','ERROR','error');
            else
                    h=waitbar(0,'Embedding...');
            for p=1:400, % computation here %
                    waitbar(p/100);
            end;

            [psnr,capa,opfile,full,file]=proses_embedd(imfile,txfile);
            close(h);
            set(handles.txt_nilaipnsr,'String',num2str(psnr));
            set(handles.txt_ukuranpesan,'String',num2str(capa));
            set(handles.txt_kapasitaspesan,'String',num2str(file));
            figure,imshow(imfile);
            figure,imshow(opfile);

            if (full==0)
                msg=strcat(int2str(capa),'bits only embedded please select a large image');
                msgbox(msg,'warning','warn');
            end;

            if (full==1)
                msgbox('SUCCESS!!!','SUCCESS');
            end;
            end;
            end;
            end;
    end
```

and this is the function to embedd text to image

```
    function[psnr,capa,opfile,full,file]= proses_embedd(P1,Q)
    P=imread(P1);
    [Pm,Pn]=size(P);
    I=P;
    fid=fopen(Q,'rt');
    [X1,co]=fread(fid,'*char');
    r=1;

    for q=1:co
       L(q)=uint8(X1(q));
    end;

    for q=1:co
     W(r:r+7)=dec2bin(L(q),8);
       r=r+8;
    end;

    file=r-1;
    x=0;

    for i=1:Pm
         if x>=(r-1)
             break;
         end;

         for j=1:2:Pn-1
             if x>=(r-1)
                 break;
         end;

         p11=double(I(i,j));
         p21=double(I(i,j+1));
         d0=(p11-p21);

         if abs(d0)<8
             w0=8;
             l0=0;
         elseif abs(d0)<16&&abs(d0)>7
             w0=8;
             l0=8;
         elseif abs(d0)>15&&abs(d0)<32
             w0=16;
             l0=16;
         elseif abs(d0)>31&&abs(d0)<64
             w0=32;
             l0=32;
         elseif abs(d0)>63&&abs(d0)<128
             w0=64;
             l0=64;
         elseif abs(d0)>127&&abs(d0)<256
             w0=128;
             l0=128;
         else
             w0=0;
         end;

         if(w0>0)
             t0=floor(log2(w0));
         else
             t0=0;
         end;

         if(t0>0)
             if(x<(r-1) && x+t0>(r-1))
                 b0=bin2dec(W(x+1:(r-1)));
                 d00=l0+b0;
                 m0=abs(d00-abs(d0));

                 if((p11>=p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                 end;

                 if((p11<p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11-floor(m0/2);
                     p01=p21+ceil(m0/2);
                 end;  

                 if((p11>=p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11-ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21+floor(m0/2);
                 end;

                 if((p11<p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                 end;  

                 block=1;
                 x=r-1; 

                 end;

                 if(x+t0)<=(r-1)
                     b0=bin2dec(W(x+1:x+t0));
                     d00=l0+b0;
                     m0=abs(d00-abs(d0));

                     if((p11>=p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                         p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                         p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                     end;

                     if((p11<p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                         p00=p11-floor(m0/2);
                         p01=p21+ceil(m0/2);
                     end;  

                     if((p11>=p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                         p00=p11-ceil(m0/2);
                         p01=p21+floor(m0/2);                  
                     end;

                     if((p11<p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                         p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                         p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                     end; 

                     block=1;
                     x=x+t0;           
                 end;
         end;

         if block==1
             p0=p00;
             p1=p01;
             I(i,j)=p0;
             I(i,j+1)=p1;
         end;

         end;
    end;

    if((i==Pm)&&(j>=Pn-20))
        full=0;
    else
        full=1;
    end;

    capa=x;
    capacity=dec2bin(capa,20);
    s=1;
    i=Pm;
    j=Pn-20;

    while(s<21)
        temp1=dec2bin(I(i,j),8);
        temp1(8)=capacity(s);
        I(i,j)=bin2dec(temp1);
        s=s+1;
        j=j+1;
    end;

    answer = inputdlg('output image name');
    answer1=strcat(answer,'.bmp');
    imwrite(I,char(answer1),'bmp');
    opfile=char(answer1);
    d = mean( (P(:)-I(:)).^2 );
    psnr = 10*log10(( 255^2/d) );
```

Comment: So you know, posting massive amounts of code is not always the best way to get help here. Specific questions with just enough code for people to run it and see and illustrate your issue are usually best. These take more work to compose. And are you looking for the `input` function possibly?

Comment: i'm sorry, i just a begineer. i'm confused how to insert message from edit text manually. could you please help me to solve the problem ?